# Conditionally Apply Gradle Plugin

Tags: android, groovy, gradle

As the title suggests I want to apply a plugin in my `build.gradle` iff a certain properties file exists in the project folder. The following attempt

```
buildscript {
    File c = file('crashlytics.properties')
    ext {
        crashlytics = c.exists();
    }
}

if (crashlytics) {
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
}
//...
```

results in the following error message

```
No such property: verboseGradlePlugin for class: java.lang.Boolean
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try:

```
if (project.file('crashlytics.properties').exists()) {
   apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Exchanging properties between buildscript and other part of the script doesn't work out-of-the-box.