# Project Gradle - dependencies only for certain flavor

Tags: android, gradle

In Android Studio there are 2 gradle files, one is containing product flavors and lib implementations and second one is project-specific one.

I need to make some parts in project-specific one only for specific product flavor:

Example of mine Gradle project file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        //Crashlytics
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'

        //Huawei SDK
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.1.300'
    }
}
```

I want `classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.1.300'` and maven `{ url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }` to be only compiled with specific product flavor.

My app is supporting `ag-connect` Huawei Map services, but recently Google declined my app from Google Play Store because it contains Huawei SDK. So I wanna completely separate everything tied to Ag-connect to separate product flavor.

I've done it for librabries and code itself, but I need to do this in this `Gradle` file too, because Google is declining my app constantly.

Also inside my second Gradle file (App:Gradle) there is plugin initialization:

```
apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
```

How can I apply this plugin only for specific flavor?

Comment: Conditionally applying a plugin should be possible as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28971066/150978

Comment: the answer in the link is not correct